# Acces to thingsboard shared attribute

Tags: javascript, iot, thingsboard

i'am trying to call a shared attribute for a device (thingbsoard) with the rule chain so i can apply an if statement on it , but i dont know how to do it , is there anyway that allow me to call attributes in rule chain please ?

this is the example i used , but i'am sure that the get function is wrong .

```
var shared_att = global.getSharedAttributeValue("threshold");
if (shared_att > 50) {
// Trigger an alarm
var alarm = {
    type: "Temperature",
    severity: "Critical",
    description: "Temperature has exceeded the threshold of 50 degrees.",
    status: "Active"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Originator attributes` rule node to fetch any type of attributes.

Comment: i have the same attribute (threshold) for three different devices , and each time i want to make an if statement that allow me to compare the telemetry input for specific device with the  threshold (shared attribute) of the same device , so i can trigger an alarm
NB: we change those attribute with widget in a dashboard

Comment: Three rule nodes: 1) `Originator attributes` 2) `Filter Script` node 3) `Create Alarm` for case than threshold attributes is, for example, less than telemetry value